# Initialize Glew from within wxGLCanvas under Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, glew, wxglcanvas

When the constuctor for my `wxGLCanvas` sub-class

```
MyGLCanvas::MyGLCanvas(wxWindow* parent)
        : wxGLCanvas(parent, wxID_ANY, 0)
{
    wxGLContext *m_context = new wxGLContext(this);
    SetCurrent(*m_context);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
}
```

is called `glewInit()` returns me the error-code for "Missing GL version".

This is only under Ubuntu, where I link with the flags `-lGLEW -lGL`, wxWidgets is version 2.8 and OpenGL 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3. Under Windows OS there is no error.

I'm thankfull for any pointers. Let me know if you need any additional information or a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated `wxWidgets` to version 3.1 and moved the `SetCurrent` and `glewInit` call from the constructor to an event-handler bound to `wxEVT_PAINT` and made sure it is called only once.

Now it works.